# Status Control color with Taipy

Tags: taipy

The status shown on the page has a red and a green color (https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/controls/). How do I make them have two or more different colors if you have more than two status. Below is the code where clicking on a toggle changes the status but everything is the same color. The id of "id=statuslog" I understand is for the three. Would it be using individual IDs "FT1", "FT2" and "FT3"? I had create a css file with the id "statuslog" but the style is the same for all items of value_tgg

Code:
from taipy import Gui

```
        value_tgg=[('TG1', 'Choice 1'), ('TG2', 'Choice 2'), ('TG3', 'Choice 3')]
        value_tgg_choice=value_tgg[0]
        val_status1= [('FT1', 'Recording'), ('FT2', 'Recorded'), ('FT3', 'Failed')]
        val_status_choice1=val_status1[0]

        page1_md="""

        ## TESTE

        <|{val_status_choice1}|status|lov={val_status1}|id=statuslog|>

        <|{value_tgg_choice}|toggle|lov={value_tgg}|on_change={on_value_tgg}|>


        """


        def on_value_tgg(state, id, action):
            print(state.value_tgg_choice)
            if state.value_tgg_choice[1]=='Choice 1':
            state.val_status_choice1=state.val_status1[1]
            print('1')
            elif state.value_tgg_choice[1]=='Choice 2':
            state.val_status_choice1=state.val_status1[2]
            print('2')
            elif state.value_tgg_choice[1]=='Choice 3':
            state.val_status_choice1=state.val_status1[0]
            print('3')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the status color is determined by the initial element of the tuple passed to the toggle.

- E represents Error, which corresponds to the red color.
- S represents Success, which corresponds to the green color.
- W represents Warning, which corresponds to the orange color.

The default color for this visual component is blue.

In the code provided, a toggle is used to select from a list of tuples, where the first element dictates a unique color each time.

```py
from taipy import Gui


list_toggle = [('E', 'Recording'),
               ('S', 'Recorded'),
               ('I', 'Failed'),
               ('W', 'Warning')]
value_toggle = list_toggle[0]

page1_md = """
# Status

<|{value_toggle}|status|>

<|{value_toggle}|toggle|lov={list_toggle}|>
"""

Gui(page1_md).run()
```

A better documentation is on the way to explain this behavior.